# Handling MySQL length=22 and decimals=31

Tags: mysql, datatypes, floating-point

I'm using MySQL's C api to determine the maximum possible value that can be stored in a specific field.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    f1 double(4,2),
    f2 double
)
```

When I get the field information for `f1` and `f2` using the API, here is what I see:

`f1`: `{ [...], length = 4, decimals = 2 }`

`f2`: `{ [...], length = 22, decimals = 31 }`

I understand that the maximum value that `f1` can store is `99.99` (total length = 4, so 4-2=2 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal).

Is it safe to assume that if a column type is `DOUBLE`, its length is `22` and its decimal is `31`, then there is no `(m, d)` specified? If so, then can we also assume that the maximum value this column can store is `1.7976931348623157E+308` (as per the docs)? Can this value ever change between different machines/operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use (m,n) on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  It is virtually useless and leads to double-roundings.

`DOUBLE` is an IEEE-754 "Double", which includes 53 significant *bits* and a range that tops out at that number given (over 1.E+308).  This is universal to nearly all languages, and machines.

There are virtually no machines / OSs today that deviate from IEEE754 in the representation of numbers.  In theory, you could see differences, but I doubt that you will.

The "22" in `information_schema.COLUMNS.numeric_precision` may come from how many characters it takes to display (but even that does not make sense).  I don't know where you got the "31".